# Displaying an integer in a TextView

Tags: android, textview, int

In my Player.java object class I have the following code

```
private static int playerAge;
```

with 
`playerAge = 18;` 
in my constructor method

```
    public static int getplayerAge() {
    return playerAge;
}
```

But when trying to get the player age in my java class which extends activity it always shows "0" instead of "18" like it's supposed too. Here's my code for that.

```
TextView playerAge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPlayerAge);
        playerAge.setText("Age: " + Integer.toString(Player.getplayerAge()));
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

By the way if I change `private static int playerAge;` from the very top, to 
`private static int playerAge = 18;` it works, just don't get why it doesn't work from the constructor method.

Player.java class

```
public class Player extends Object {

    //Instance Data
    private static String playerName;
    private static int playerAge = 1;
    private static boolean sterile; 

    //Default Constructor
    public Player() {
        playerName = "";
        playerAge = 5; //For some reason you have to inetiate the playerAge in the instance data for
                            //it to be able to read it...
        sterile = true; //Default Value
    }

    //Constructor
    public Player(String pName, int pAge, boolean isSterile)    {
        playerName = pName;
        playerAge = pAge;
        sterile = isSterile;
    }


    //Accessor Methods (Getters)
    public static String getplayerName() {
        return playerName;
    }

    public static int getplayerAge() {
        return playerAge;
    }

    public static boolean getplayerDiseasedState() { //Sterile or not?
        return sterile;
    }


    //Mutator Methods (Setters)
    public static void setPlayerName(String name) {
        playerName = name;
    }

    public static void setplayerAge(int age) {
        playerAge = age;
    }

    public static boolean setSterileState(boolean diseased) {
        return sterile = diseased;
    }


    //toString (Accessor)
    public String toString() {
        String toString =   "Player Name: "+ playerName + "\n" +
                "Player Age: " + playerAge + "\n" +
                "Player Diseased: "  + sterile + "\n";
    return toString;
        }



     }
```

Comment: are you sure you're calling the constructor before you're calling Player.getPlayerAge()?

Comment: Can you post the entire code?

Comment: I posted it @ElectronicGeek

Comment: If you can, make them non-static, is there a point for private variables to be static?

Comment: I have to keep them static or I get errors @ElectronicGeek

Comment: Ok, I'm think there's something wrong with them being static, I think, beyond that I do not know, which constructor are you calling in the activity?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the Integer.toString() bit. Just use:

```
player.setText("Age: " + Player.getPlayerAge());
```

Comment: I highly doubt this is the reason why the TextView is showing 0 instead of 18

Comment: This won't work, does the same thing practically. Tried it just to make sure, and it didn't work. Thank you though.

Comment: Simple & perfectly solution for show integer as string) +1